# Ruby - Convert Day Of Week To Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How would you convert a day string (i.e. `"Monday"` or `"Wednesday"`), into the corresponding wday integer (`1` or `3`)?

I've come up with this convoluted way

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week("Monday".downcase.to_sym).wday
```

Comment: `{sunday: 0, monday: 1, tuesday: 2, wednesday: 3, thursday: 4, friday: 5, saturday: 6 }`
will work.

Comment: Be careful since `beginning_of_week` depends on a rails config value (you can have any day to be the first of the week) https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

Comment: There's probably a better built-in method to do it, but you can always do `Date::DAYNAMES.find_index("Wednesday")`

Comment: thanks for the comments. was wondering if there was an easier built-in way. using a dictionary seems to be the cleanest / fastest. As for beginning_of_week returning a default value, that's not an issue since I'm passing in an argument.

Comment: I also find `Date.parse("Wednesday").wday` pretty clean

Comment: When you expect Monday to return `1`, would you consider Sunday to return `0` or `7`?

Comment: @Ideid I think your `Date::DAYNAMES.find_index("Wednesday")` is the cleanest and the most robust. Can you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can parse it using [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
Date.strptime('Monday', '%A').wday
#=> 1

Date.strptime('Wednesday', '%A').wday
#=> 3
```

The intermediate date object refers to the weekday in the current week:

```
Date.today
#=> #<Date: 2018-11-20 ...>

Date.strptime('Monday', '%A')
#=> #<Date: 2018-11-19 ...>
```

You can also use [`_strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_strptime) (prefixed with an underscore) to extract the date elements which happen to be `:wday` for a single weekday:

```
Date._strptime('Monday', '%A')
#=> {:wday=>1}
```

Comment: Nice tip about `_strptime` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CHRONIC gem.

> Chronic is a Ruby natural language date/time parser written by Tom
>   Preston-Werner (@mojombo) which takes surprisingly human readable text
>   and converts it to dates. (http://robdodson.me/playing-with-ruby-dates/)

You can use like this:

```
require 'chronic'

Chronic.parse('Monday').wday
=> 1
```

I hope help you!

Comment: No need for a gem actually (at least on ruby 2.5.1): `Date.parse("Monday").wday`

Comment: Ohh!! I didn't know. Thank you!!